# GORM: lazily save

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

a) I try to save a contact item belonging to the datastore domain classe as following:

```
class Contacts implements Serializable{

    static belongsTo = [dataStore:DataStore]

    DataStore dataStore
    String emailaddress
```

Class DS:

```
class DataStore implements Serializable{

    static belongsTo = [service:Service,user:User]
    static hasMany = [users:User,contacts:Contacts,groups:Groups]

    Service service
    User user
    User users
    List<Contacts> contacts
```

b) At the controller level i create a contact as an ajax request:

```
def create() {
        String key = session["KEY"]
        DataStore ds = session["DS"]
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        def c = new Contacts(dataStore:ds,emailaddress:params.contacts.email)
        if (c.validate()) {
            ds.addToContacts(c).save(flush:true)
            c.save()
```

c) The following error prevents the saving

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: $$$.DataStore.contacts, no session or session was closed. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: $$$.DataStore.contacts, no session or session was closed
    at $$$$.ContactsController$$EO4iccbg.create(ContactsController.groovy:115)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:149)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:259)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

A session is active ... what does it means ? Any idea to solve this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After lookine a while on hibernate side about GrailsOpenSessionInViewFilter, I finally came to a solution by resetting the dataStore session like this:

```
def dsx = DataStore.get(ds.id)
```